# Changing from Unity to Gnome3 on 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, gnome, updates

I just installed Gnome 3 and all is working but should I also remove Unity if I will not be using it?

I dont want to burden the Ubuntu servers by downloading Unity updates

Comment: I see no reason to run a DE such as Unity or Gnome on a server. Most of server management is command line apt-get .... , start/stop services, edit config files, all of which can be done as easily via ssh as by gnome-terminal. If you want a graphical interface use any of the web consoles such as cockpit or webmin - http://cockpit-project.org/ and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI "Juju, Puppet, Chef, Landscape, Cassandra, Fabric, and a host of other remote configuration and management tools are very helpful for servers and can automate lots of tasks."

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think I must have read his question backwards - I thought he was worried about unduly stressing the download servers :)

Answer (score 2):

Those extra packages will take up some space on your harddisk - but that's all, unless you are on a metered connection where every kB data matters.

Compared to the amount of downloads happening every day from the Ubuntu servers your part doesn't make any difference. So there is no outside reason for you to remove them.